# Full clone of running Linux Server (Centos7)

Tags: linux, centos, clone, linux-kvm

I need to create a completely identical linux system on another machine.

Now I have a linux server up and running with Centos 7 installed. It acts as a server for some web resource. Also it runs in a KVM virtual machine. 
So I have no chance to boot from a livecd anyway.

I can't stop my system as well, only for a couple of minutes, but this won't help anyway.

So my question is how to create a complete clone of running system.

I have the following disk layout

```
/dev/mapper/VG-lv_root 100492376 21506376  73858220  23% /
devtmpfs                 1930476        0   1930476   0% /dev
tmpfs                    1941024        0   1941024   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    1941024    57980   1883044   3% /run
tmpfs                    1941024        0   1941024   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                 499656   201976    271468  43% /boot
overlay                100492376 21506376  73858220  23% /var/lib/docker/overlay/2a5e41fa94f64ffefaaa4a644cb8413e1579d877e35187bae2cf38772acbdb1a/merged
shm                        65536        0     65536   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/5c831624ff9e4d0dbcdf73120df94a601f0a29cb34716d5c7906ef29d778c938/shm
overlay                100492376 21506376  73858220  23% /var/lib/docker/overlay/3d904f042dc29ac06871cd301b89c4c8fadd254fe24855369279b5df0343968c/merged
shm                        65536        0     65536   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/e20b5a4bcce42d6a8d33ae7e66e33150782960b60babf65d699c52c4ba7ae24f/shm
tmpfs                     388208        0    388208   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs                     388208        0    388208   0% /run/user/1001
```

I want to clone this system into another machine that is a KVM as well. I am running Proxmox on my home server. So I have any kind of access to this machine.

Please suggest how to create a complete clone in this case ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://superuser.com/questions/396800/is-it-possible-to-dd-the-current-disk-you-are-booted-off

Comment: You are using lvm so you probably can create clone using lvm snapshot and dd.

Comment: @atype Could you provide more information how to do this ?